# Identification of unique profile with Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring

I've got a question on Paypal's IPN.
After creating subscription profile (recurring payment profile), the confirmation of type 'recurring_payment_profile_created' is received on IPN.
After proceeding payment, the confirmation of type 'recurring_payment' is received on IPN.
The question is how should I identify that the payment (recurring_payment) belongs to the unique(specific) profile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`recurring_payment_id`. This will be a recurring payment profile ID in the form of I-xxxxxxxx.
This should be included in all recurring payment IPN posts.

Comment: Thanks McGeek! It`s very help for me!